# python os.rename renaming everything back to normal

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this block of code I rename everything in the c:\picturesandfolders directory and their subdirectory file's but I've got a problem should I use files.append method to bypass folder's because folder's should not get renamed only file's, also How can I remove the rename tag I gave to files? Put everything back to normal with 1 script because renaming them manually will take ages for me.

EDIT: Ok I found the solution but does anyone have a more logical explanation.

```
import os
current_dir = __file__[ : __file__.rfind(os.sep)+1]
my_working_file = __file__.replace(current_dir, '')


folder = 'C:\\picturesandvideos'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file in [my_working_file]:
            continue
        all_folders = os.path.join(root + '\\')
        source = all_folders + file
        print(all_folders)


        destination = all_folders + f'L0cked!_{file}'
        locked_tag = 'L0cked!_'
        remove_locked = all_folders + f'{file}'
        if locked_tag in locked_filename:  #to make everything normal.
            old_name = (locked_filename.replace(locked_tag,('')))
            os.rename(source, old_name)

    # Renaming the file
        os.rename(source, destination)  #this will change the name with L0cked!_
```

Comment: That's exactly what you're telling it to do!  You need to join the directory name to the filename for *both* parameters to `rename()`.

Comment: Mind, to _put them back_ requires going back in time; when you moved the files without making any record of their prior locations (and presumably without having a backup), you put yourself in a state from which absent filesystem/OS-specific features that it's outside our scope to recommend, there's no unbreaking that egg.

Comment: I think This need's some kind of algorithm, I tried os.listdir but that only change's the folder name and move's it to desktop

Comment: jasonharper already told you exactly how to stop your code from doing this again in the future. But when you say "put them back to where they belong", that's not about stopping it from happening again, that's about undoing what already happened in the past, and that's a very different question.

Comment: so there is no way of doing this Im trying to build my own NordLocker here which is a service provided by nordvpn, maybe I can add an extention? to normal extention over my extention? ex: .L0cked

Comment: Also I meant change the name then put it where they belong this code is buggy right now and I tried everything but couldn't figure it out.